# How to mimic spacing around \bullet with \DeclareMathOperator?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I'm trying to define `\conjunction` by means of `\textbullet` instead of `\bullet`, since the latter looks too big in logical formulas.  How can I make the spacing around `\conjunction` to behave like the spacing around `\bullet` when there is an opening parenthesis just after it?

Compare (2) and (2'):

[image: Examples]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\DeclareMathOperator\conjunction{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}\begin{align}
\intertext {Good spacing but bad size:}
(\exists x(\forall y(\phi(y)\equiv y\!=\!x)&\bullet Gx)\supset\psi)\\
\exists  x(\forall y(\phi(y)\equiv y\!=\!x)&\bullet (Gx\supset\psi))\\
\intertext {Good size and spacing:}
(\exists x(\forall y(\phi(y)\equiv y\!=\!x)&\conjunction Gx)\supset\psi)\\
\intertext {Good size but bad spacing:}
\exists  x(\forall y(\phi(y)\equiv y\!=\!x)&\conjunction (Gx\supset\psi))
\end{align}\end{document}
```

This won't do:

```
\DeclareMathOperator\conjunction{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\textbullet\ }}
```

because it adds an unwanted extra space to (1').

Comment: You don't want it to be a math operator, use `\newcommand*\conjuntion{\mathbin{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\textbullet}}}`.

Comment: @eduardo.tex: ...or use `\mathrel`.

Comment: @Werner No, `\bullet` is `\mathbin`.

Comment: @egreg: True, if `\conjunction` is a `bin`ary operator.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand what's the text about, but may be OP was using `\bullet` because of the symbol while the correct would be a mathrel.

Comment: Thanks! `\conjunction` is supposed to do duty as `\wedge`.

Comment: @eduardo.tex Then `\mathbin` is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\DeclareMathOperator` is only for `\log`-like functions. Here you want this symbol to be a binary operator, so you need `\mathbin`

```
\newcommand*\conjunction{\mathbin{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\textbullet}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `pict2e`. The bullet size can be adjusted, via an optional argument (default: `2.1\unitlength`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{graphicx, pict2e}

\newcommand\conjunction[1][2.1]{\mathbin{\raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\circle*{2.1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \intertext {Good size and spacing:}
  ( ∃ x(∀ y(ϕ(y) ≡ y\!=\!x) & \conjunction Gx) ⊃ \psi)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are in math mode `\raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{..}` could be a `\vcenter{\hbox{..}}`.