# Spacing of \tilde{\otimes}

Tags: spacing, math-operators

How can I make the spacing of the two symbols, `\otimes` and `\tildeotimes`, identical?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tildeotimes}{\tilde{\otimes}}
\begin{document}
    $a \otimes b$

    $a \tildeotimes b$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\mathbin{}` around `\tildeotimes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tildeotimes}{\tilde{\otimes}}
\begin{document}
    $a \otimes b$

    $a \mathbin{\tildeotimes} b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Per the answer at [How to mimic spacing around \bullet with \DeclareMathOperator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236338/how-to-mimic-spacing-around-bullet-with-declaremathoperator/236341#236341), `\DeclareMathOperator` "is only for `\log`-like functions."  The preferred implementation is, therefore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\tildeotimes}{\mathbin{\tilde{\otimes}}}
\begin{document}
    $a \otimes b$

    $a \tildeotimes b$
\end{document}
```